# Нужна ли запятая перед "по адресу"?

Tags: запятые

Обязуюсь выполнить работы по устройству отведения сточных вод с реконструкцией площадки первого этажа по адресу: ул. Ново-вокзальная, д. 61.

Comment: В деловом стиле обычно не ставят двоеточие перед адресом.